# Calculation of Restriction Map

Tags: equivariant-cohomology

Question:Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $X$ be a G-set. $K$ be a subgroup of $G$. let $i$ be a group homomorphism from $K$ to $G$ . I am looking for the map $$ i^{*} : H^{\alpha}_{G}(X,M) \rightarrow H^{i^{*}\alpha}_{K}(i^*X,i^*M).$$How can I compute this map $i^{*}$ for a constant Mackey functor $M$? Where $\alpha$ belongs to $RO(G)$ and $i^{*}X = X$ with $K$ - action induced by $G$. Note: For constant $G$- Mackecy fuctor $M$, $i^{*}M$ is $M$ as constant Mackey functor of $K$. Can anyone give some hint atleast for $X= point$.

Comment: I don't think we even know $H_G^*(*;M)$ for all finite abelian groups, in $RO(G)$ grading. However, the calculations I've seen are Mackey-functor valued, so include all the restriction maps and transfers.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble:  Thank you very much  for your comment.I am interested in $ G = Z/6 $,  $ M = Z/6$-constant Mackey functor and $\alpha = \xi^2 - \xi$, where $\xi$- is nontrivial irreducible representation of $Z/6$ with out fixed point.Is it possible to find $i^*$  in this  setting?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only computations I know of are for $G = {\mathbb Z}/p$ for $p$ prime. (Look for papers by L. Gaunce Lewis, Jeff Caruso, and William Kronholm.) I think I saw a paper also looking at prime power order, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble : Thank you for your valuable comment.I had read most of the papers of Gaunce Lewis and Jeff Caruso(just One paper).But I never saw any paper on the calculation $H^*_{G}(*,M)$ for $|G| = p^n$.It will be nice if you can find it for me.I have another question that'll help me for the above calculation.Question:What is $Z/6$-complex structure of $S(\xi + \xi^2 + 2\sigma)$ ? Where $\xi$ ,$\xi^2$ are defined in above comment and $\sigma$ is 1 real dimensional sign representation of $Z/6$.

Comment: I must be misremembering, as I can't find any calculations now for groups other than ${\mathbb Z}/p$. I don't know the structure on $S(\xi+\xi^2+2\sigma)$ offhand, but if I wanted to work it out I would first put structures on $D(\xi)$, $D(\xi^2)$, and $D(2\sigma)$, then take their product and look at what the structure on the boundary is.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble: Thank you very much.You are such an inspiration for me.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble:We know that $S(V+W)= S(V)*S(W)$.Now I know the $Z/6$ CW complex structures of $S(\xi^2)$ and $S(2\sigma)$.How can I compute the attaching maps for $S(\xi^2 + 2\sigma)$?

Comment: As I said, I tend to think of $S(V+W) = \partial D(V+W) = \partial [D(V)\times D(W)]$. The chain complex of $D(V)\times D(W)$ wants to look like the tensor product of the two chain complexes, except for one wrinkle: a product of ${\mathbb Z}/6$ cells is not a single cell, but a disjoint union of several. If you view the chains as Mackey functors and use the box product, this should be taken into account correctly. That may or may not give you a good handle on the geometry, but that's how I would approach the algebra.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble : I know the explicit $Z/6$-CW($\xi^2$)-complex structure of $D(\xi^2)$ . I am looking for an explicit calculation for $Z/6$-CW($\xi^2$)-complex structure of $D(2\xi^2)$  .it'll be great if you kindly calculate the explicit (geometric) structure of it.

Comment: Sorry: I've told you how I would go about it, but I have too many other projects of my own at the moment to spend time on the actual calculation.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble : Is there any internal Kunneth formula for integer graded Bredon cohomology theory , i.e. We know the integer graded Bredon cohomology of $G$-spaces $X ,Y$ respectively  and we wanted to know about the Bredon cohomology of $X \times Y$ ?

Comment: I don't think I've seen it written out (or done so myself), and it's been a while since I thought about it, but I think it goes like this: If you view Bredon cohomology as Mackey-functor valued, then there's a Kunneth spectral sequence whose $E_2$ term involves Tor groups taken in the category of Mackey functors, i.e., derived functors of the box product. It converges to the cohomology of the product, with appropriate finiteness conditions to get convergence.